# How do I carve a 2D Betty Boop cake?

Tags: cake

Help! This is my first 2D carved cake and I am very frustrated. Do I need to have the cake stacked and dirty iced or dry stacked to carve?

I know to freeze the cake but I hate to make all that buttercream icing and blue berry filling just to carve it away. It's a Betty Boop. What should I do?

Comment: Take a lesson from these quick videos (3 parts). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uR_FfD2XZno, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkhS8GoKKe4, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr1xfVeUGeo.  After that, come back here with *specific* questions, and we'll be able to be of more help. This is the book she refers to in the videos: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0316702056?tag=cakedarla-20.

Comment: Hi Pam. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I proposed an edit to tidy up your question a bit. Are you following a specific recipe/decorating procedure? It would be very helpful if you could edit your original post and include that information. It may help us have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.